# Typescript error - Assignment to property of function parameter 'state' in ReduxJS Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

This is my code -

```
type LoginState = {
  loading: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'succeeded' | 'failed';
  role: string;
  error: string;
};

const initialState: LoginState = {
  loading: 'idle',
  role: '',
  error: '',
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(authUser.pending, (state: LoginState) => {
        state.loading = 'pending';
      })
      .addCase(authUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = 'failed';
        console.log('action', action);
      });
  },
});
```

And I am getting this error on TS -

[image]

I am not really sure, how I can resolve this. I have already added interfaces but seems I am missing something.

Can you guys help.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a linting rule you have setup/configured in your project. You can either completely disable the rule (*not recommended*), or override the rule in the few places where it makes sense, like here in the reducer function where you *are* directly setting properties on the `state` object. Add a comment that disables the specific rule for the next line of code.

Example:

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(authUser.pending, (state: LoginState) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        state.loading = 'pending';
      })
      .addCase(authUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        state.loading = 'failed';
      });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont declare the type of the state. The own library should type it correctly as `WritableDraft<LoginState>` (It uses the provided type at `initialState`):

```
      .addCase(authUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = 'pending';
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still the same error.